# Why match doesn't give me score?

Tags: starcraft-2

After 3 weeks breaks I've played 4 matches (1 yesterday, 3 today). All of them won, but the problem is that on the profile page 2 first matches give me score (in "Result" column I see "Win (+30)"), but two latest - contains only "Win"?

What does that mean?

And Why I didn't receive my scores?

Thanks.

P.S. Link to profile on battle net: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/2358878/1/BuddaSoft/matches

**EDIT**: after that I lost 3 matches in a row - rating was not changed either... ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your issue, but I had this once before where the +/- didn't show up till a couple days later

Comment: I don't have an official blizzard link, but there were issues a few days ago as well where ladder games were not awarding win/loss points.  It appears this is currently happening again, there are several posts on reddit, battle.net forums, and in the in-game chat channels that are reporting the same thing.

Comment: Gotta state the obvious, but were they placement matches?

Comment: @tenfour If you go to his link, you'll see he has 51 wins this season. So they can't be placement matches.

Comment: In 2v2 you will do placement matches any time you play with a new ally.

Comment: Guess we need the OP to confirm whether or not he played all 7 of those matches with two different partners/matchups.

Comment: I played like 10 games yesterday, only the 2 first game gave me pts all other never changed my scores. There is a problem with battle.net which will probably be solved today with the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blizzard had said that they were turning off point increase/decrease because of instability with the servers. They don't want a bunch of people complaining because they lost points due to disconnects. The downtime was pretty short if I remember, which is why it probably only happened for a few games.